# Merging of Maps such that values of common keys are added in resulting map

Tags: java, hashmap

I know how to solve this problem using a Map.Entry<>, but I want to know if it can be done in some shorter way.

Problem Statement:
If I have to merge two maps and Suppose both of them have a common key say **k1** with different values say **v1 and v2**.
Now, the resulting map should have key-value pair as
<**k1, v1 + v2**>

It'll be a great help if someone can suggest a shorter method.

Comment: Read the Javadoc of Map merge

Comment: Now, the resulting map should have key-value pair as ? what next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `Map.merge()` may help you in this regard. From Oracle's docs:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.htm

This will check to see if a value exists in a map, and apply a function to it if it is.

The function to combine values depends on your specific use case. For example, if the keys of both maps represent IP addresses, and the values represent the number of times they accessed a URL, it might make sense to add them. In this case, the resulting code would be

```
Map<String, Integer> map1, map2;  // populated and not null

map1.forEach((k, v) -> map2.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
```

For clarity, this code:

- Iterates over every pair in `map1` (using `map1.forEach()`)
- Applies the function `(k, v) -> map2.merge(...);` to each item.
- `map2.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2)` adds the 2 values together if they both exist, and selects the one that does exist if only one exists.

The result is stored in `map2`.